# Can't access to my VPS

Tags: centos, ip, remote-access, blocking

I try to connect to my VPS but I can't, even if i use an another computer. But when I use a different connection (other IP) it works.

So I was wondering, why my VPS blacklist my IP ? And where can I change this ?

I'm using CENTOS.

Thanks

---

I got with iptables :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Try `iptables --list` and see if there's any rules for SSH.

Comment: iptables are clear... any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure SSH is not blocked on your end? I know it sounds silly, but it's possible. I guess the only way to test is to try SSHing to something else.

Comment: I try SSH from an another IP and it works ...

It is not just SSH, it's everything, I can't access to my VPS at all, port 80, 21, 22... I can't do anything.

Comment: Could you please specify the error you get when you try to SSH from your machine? That could help.

Comment: I got nothing. Http, ftp, ssh all give me a time out.